# How to write a groovy-filter with tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, groovy, filter

First, no Grails.

I just want to write an Auth.groovy as a filter:

```
package my.auth;

public class Auth implements Filter {
    //...
}
```

My web.xml has something like :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>GroovyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>groovy.servlet.GroovyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GroovyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.groovy</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And how to config the web.xml let the auth-filter run please?

Comment: just compile your groovy into a class, put into a jar/war, and set classname as a filter. see the examples: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html

Comment: @daggett Thank you. means not like the groovy-servlet, I can not just write a groovy-filter with out compile.

Comment: you could write own implementation of parametrized filter that will use groovy class loader and  delegate filtering to groovy classes (files).